# Same function for all queries onSuccess react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a use-case where I would like to run the same function `onSuccess` for all mutations and queries globally instead of having to set the same function on each individual query (i have a lot of queries)

I have a bunch of queries like so

```
const q1 = useQuery(
  "q1",
  async () => {
    return await axios
      .get(`/some/path`)
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .catch((e) => CustomError(e));
  },
  {
    onSuccess: () => generic(),
  }
);

const q2 = useQuery(
  "q2",
  async () => {
    return await axios
      .get(`/some/path`)
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .catch((e) => CustomError(e));
  },
  {
    onSuccess: () => generic(),
  }
);

const q1 = useQuery(
  "q3",
  async () => {
    return await axios
      .get(`/some/path`)
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .catch((e) => CustomError(e));
  },
  {
    onSuccess: () => generic()
  }
);

function generic() {
    return "should be set globally and run on ever OnSuccess event"
}
```

However, I would like to set this globally for all quires, something like this

```
const queryCache = new QueryClient({
  defaultConfig: {
    queries: {
      onSuccess: () => {
        return "should be set globally and run on ever OnSuccess event";
      },
    },
  },
});

const q1 = useQuery("q1", async () => {
  return await axios
    .get(`/some/path`)
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((e) => CustomError(e));
});

const q2 = useQuery("q2", async () => {
  return await axios
    .get(`/some/path`)
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((e) => CustomError(e));
});

const q1 = useQuery("q3", async () => {
  return await axios
    .get(`/some/path`)
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((e) => CustomError(e));
});
```

I have searched the docs for about an hour for this type of functionality but cannot find anything

Comment: Is it related to react-query? You can just wrap all the requests with a function that handle success. Something like: `function callAPI(path) { return axios.get(path).then((res) => res.data).catch((e) => CustomError(e) }`, then `const q1 = useQuery("q3", () => callAPI('some/path'))`.

Comment: This is no diffrent from the code i already have and also dosen't address the issue. Thanks though.

Comment: Well, it does different because you handle success once, there you can call `generic()` but as you wish :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find out how to solve this for my use-case, it was a case of setting the OnSuccess function using `setDefaultOptions`.

turns out this code

```
const queryCache = new QueryClient({
  defaultConfig: {
    queries: {
      onSuccess: () => {
        return "should be set globally and run on ever OnSuccess event";
      },
    },
  },
});
```

wasn't doing anything, instead i set the defaults through the function

```
const queryCache = new QueryClient();

queryCache.setDefaultOptions({
  queries: {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    onSuccess: () => console.log("Got IM!"),
  },
});
```

This triggers `console.log("Got Im!")` onSuccess for every time i call my API which is the desired outcome for my use-case.

i can see that `const queryCache = new QueryClient();` does have a constructor that takes `defaultOptions` however, for whatever reason they do not set.

**EDIT**

turns out it does work passing it to the constructor, its just this code was written when using an older version of react-query when the key was `defaultConfig` instead of `defaultOptions`. This code also works (aswell as the solution above)

```
const queryCache = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      onSuccess: () => console.log("Got IM!"),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an open PR for that exact use case: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/pull/2404

It adds the possibility to have a global onSuccess callback on the queryCache.

Comment: Ah damn should of posted earlier or check PR's, wasted alot of time. Thanks man. ill try think of something hacky i can do for now